# Proper use of boolean/case?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having issues figuring out if I properly wrote this function. It'll be fed a string that either contains a "%" or a "#" as the last character ie. "TA_PQ_SI02_%". I just want this function to tell me if it's a % or #.

Did I do this in the most effiecient/proper way? I think not, and would like to learn why.

```
Private Function numberOrPercentCheck(ByVal cleanCode As String) As Boolean
    Select Case cleanCode 
        Case Right(cleanCode , 1) = "#"
            numberOrPercentCheck= True
        Case Right(cleanCode , 1) = "%"
            numberOrPercentCheck= False
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Error: " & cleanCode & " is not formatted properly with a # or % at the end, and has been set to a default #"
            numberOrPercentCheck = True
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: `Select Case Right(cleanBMCode, 1)` and then `Case "#"` etc

Comment: also look at cleanBMCode versus cleanCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just want a Boolean:

```
Private Function numberOrPercentCheck(ByVal cleanCode As String) As Boolean
    numberOrPercentCheck = Right(cleanCode, 1) = "#"
End Function
```

When you need a third possibility:

```
Private Function numberOrPercentCheck(ByVal cleanCode As String) As Variant
    Select Case Right(cleanCode, 1)
        Case "#": numberOrPercentCheck = True
        Case "%": numberOrPercentCheck = False
        Case Else: numberOrPercentCheck = "Error: " & cleanCode & " is not formatted properly with a # or % at the end"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Would you make the default value of `numberOrPercentCheck = True` at the top of the function or would you add something on the next line after `Case Else` that sets `numberOrPercentCheck = True` if I want to execute the "#" option if neither? Or would you alternative just change `Case "#": numberOrPercentCheck = False` and the other to True? And would you say that Case is the absolute best way for a third possibility?

Comment: The default of first top-function is False, when you want your Else Clause also set to True then you have only 2 options and I would go for the first-function. (just change # to %). When there are more possibilities I think that select case is easy to read/follow/adjust.